# Create a UIView Subclass which auto arranges its sub views according to its frame?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, gridview, uiview

I have requirement like - I have to create a subclass of UIView (eg. MyView) in which it will have 4 sub views (UIImageVeiws, UILabels) arranged 2X2 in position.When I create object of my UIView subclass (MyView object) and gives a default frame those 4 sub views within the view should be arranged according to its super views frame which I am passing.

If I resize or reframe MyView object frame, the 4 subviews sholud get rearraged (size, spacing, origin) according the new frame which I have given to its super view.

I am facing problems to achieve this, can anyone help me out how to achieve this. My code should be generic with respect to my subclass. Even If i remove any of the 4 subview's the remaining 3 views should get arranged within its entire super view.

Thank you.

Comment: set the subview frame relative to the superview. it should do the trick. By the way what have you tried?. Do you have a specific problem?.

Answer (score 0):

The method you need to implement is `-(void)layoutSubviews`.

This will be called automatically whenever the frame of your view changes, and at other appropriate times. Inside this method you can access the size of the parent view and layout the various subviews you have.

If you need to force a layout at a particular time, for example after changing certain properties on your view, you can call `[view setNeedsLayout]`.